# Kile Live Preview: auto-reload without saving?

Tags: kile

In Kile 2.9.91, is it possible to have the preview automatically refresh after a certain time of no modifications of the code? Just like in Gummi.

Comment: whats Kile?  What's Gummi?

Comment: click on / move mouse over the tag of this question

Answer (score 0):

In v2.9.93, it's possible to select between compile after saving and periodic refresh::

Settings -> Configure Kile -> Live Preview

But I guess that ship sailed long ago :-D

Having said that, I find problems with the .out file sometimes being corrupted, so if I use it, I use it with appropriate trepidation